# How do I ask kafka which topics have extraordinary overrides?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-topic

I understand my default retention period, but I want to see if any topics have special overrides for the retention period.

I've tried using the kafka-topics, but it doesn't connect with zookeeper.

`kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides`

I expect this output to be basically nothing but I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZooKeeperClient.scala:268)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:264)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:264)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:264)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:97)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1693)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:57)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my zookeeper param wasn't correct, zookeeper is not hosted on the kafka server. This worked:

`kafka-topics --zookeeper myactualzookeeperserver.com:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides`